# Getting unexpected result in regex

Tags: regex, sed

I am using below regex with command for removing string from the line but my regex is not working as per my expectation.

```
sed -ie "s/^\s*worker\.\(.*\)\.balance_workers=\(.*\)wallet,*\(.*\)/worker.\1.balance_workers=\2\3/"
```

**My line is:**

```
worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=wallet,wallet2
```

**Result** i am getting

```
worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=wallet,2
```

I am **expecting**

```
worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=wallet2
```

but if i am **using**

```
sed -ie "s/^\s*worker\.\(.*\)\.balance_workers=\(.*\)wallet2,*\(.*\)/worker.\1.balance_workers=\2\3/"
```

getting the **expected result**

```
worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=wallet
```

Comment: If there is always a comma before the last `wallet`, use [`^[[:blank:]]*worker\.\(.*\)\.balance_workers=\(.*\),wallet\(.*\)` pattern](https://regex101.com/r/AD9zfF/1). (Do not copy/paste it from the comment, if you want to try it, copy from regex101.) The reason for the result is that the `.*` before `worker` makes it match the last `worker` in the string and as the `,*` does not have to match any commas (`,*` - 0+ commas) the `worker` with a comma is not backtracked to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it's not working for me

Comment: Please read the content carefully my issue is wallet string not with worker string.

Comment: @HarjeetSingh, You can try this : `sed 's/=wallet,\(.*\)/=\1/g' file`

Comment: Thanks it's working but if also have remove wallet2 in some other scenario then it would not work.

Comment: @HarjeetSingh I confused `wallet` with `worker` in my comment description. And [my suggestion works](https://ideone.com/u3JO18).

Comment: @HarjeetSingh, I have added an answer and shows the error in your `sed` expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/=wallet,\(.*\)/=\1/g' file
```

From your `sed` ( Working ):

```
sed -e "s/^\s*worker\.\(.*\)\.balance_workers=\(.*\)wallet,\(.*\)/worker.\1.balance_workers=\2\3/" file
```

Problem is :

```
sed -e "s/^\s*worker\.\(.*\)\.balance_workers=\(.*\)wallet,*\(.*\)/worker.\1.balance_workers=\2\3/"
                                                           ^
                                                         You do not need this '*'
```

**EDIT:**

Use this `sed`:

```
sed -Ee 's/=(.*)wallet2($|,(.*))/=\1\3/g' -e 's/,$//' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=wallet1,wallet,wallet2

$ sed -Ee 's/=(.*)wallet($|,(.*))/=\1\3/g' -e 's/,$//' file
worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=wallet1,wallet2

$ sed -Ee 's/=(.*)wallet1($|,(.*))/=\1\3/g' -e 's/,$//' file
worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=wallet,wallet2

$ sed -Ee 's/=(.*)wallet2($|,(.*))/=\1\3/g' -e 's/,$//' file
worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=wallet1,wallet
```

Comment: Thank's!!!!! It's perfectly working for me in case of wallet but in other scenario i also have to remove wallet2 it's not working ...

Comment: What do you mean "not working in wallet2". Can you paste your `sed` ?

Comment: I also have to delete wallet2 again....                                                         sed -e "s/^\s*worker\.\(.*\)\.balance_workers=\(.*\)wallet2\,\(.*\)/worker.\1.balance_workers=\2\3/"

Comment: Because i am doing some deployment task so first i have to remove wallet then wallet2

Comment: I case of wallet your suggestion working fine and in case of wallet my regex is working fine but i want single regex for both case

Comment: @HarjeetSingh, Updated answer.

Comment: @HarjeetSingh, Glad it worked for you. Consider upvoting it by clicking up arrow in left side of an answer.

Comment: hey if I am using same sed command its giving me comma again                            sed -Ee 's/^\s*worker(.*).balance_workers=(.*)wallet($|,(.*))/worker\1.balance_workers=\2\3/'                                                                      worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=,wallet2

Answer (score 0):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you in same.

```
sed 's/\(.*,\)\([^[:digit:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3/g'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
worker.walletloadbalancer.balance_workers=wallet,2
```

Comment: Yes, exactly i am getting the same result .

Comment: Yes ,  But when i read sed -ie then getting error please my below answer.